# Generation of random numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given two probability density functions $d_1$ and $d_2$ and correlation coefficient $\rho$ how to generate two sequence of random numbers with given densities and $\rho$?

Is it possible to use copulas, or there is some other way?

Comment: Is $d_1$ and $d_2$ Gaussian ?

Comment: @anup. No, they can be arbitrary.

Comment: In the general situation, specifying the two marginal distributions and the correlation coefficient does not specify the joint distribution, which means that the problem of sampling is not well-posed. The well-posed problem is when you have a joint distribution specified and want to sample from it.

Comment: This is along the same lines as Ian's comment, but it's also possible that there doesn't even exist a joint distribution for two given marginals and a correlation, so your question doesn't have an answer in general.  Take a simple counterexample like $d_1$ being a normal density, $d_2$ a Cauchy density, and $\rho = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I am assuming that densities are guassian.

Choose two sets of weights, $w_1$ and $1-w_1$, the first set and the second set as $w_2$ and $1-w_2$, and let the standard deviation of the two densities be $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

Now the variances are 1) $Var_{I} =  w_1^2\sigma_1^2 + (1-w_2)^2\sigma_2^2 + 2w_1(1-w_1)\rho \sigma_1\sigma_2$

The other variance 2) is $Var_{II} = w_2^2\sigma_2^2 + (1-w_2)^2\sigma_2^2 + 2w_2(1-w_2)\rho \sigma_1\sigma_2$

Find the standard deviations from these two variances.  Now find the mean of the two sets  wit $\mu_I = w_1\mu_1 + (1-w_1)\mu_2$ and $\mu_{II} = w_2\mu_1 + (1-w_2)\mu_2$

Use the NORMINV function together with RAND():

$=NORMINV(RAND(),(\mu_{I}),(\sigma_{I}))$ for the first set of random numbers and 
$=NORMINV(RAND(),(\mu_{II}),(\sigma_{II}))$ for the second set of random numbers.

Thanks

Satish

Comment: What if densities are arbitrary?

Comment: As long as you know the type of distribution, you can always choose the inverse of that distribution to generate random sequences and I am hoping that you have the inverse function of that distribution in EXCEL. As far as the mean and variance are concerned, the above formulas are readily acceptable and the method of choosing weights are also applicatble

Answer (score 0):

If they are Gaussian and zero mean
Let $X_1 \sim d_1$ and $X_2 \sim d_2$

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \rho \\\rho & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Let $L$ be such that $A=LL^T$ (Use SVD to create $L$)

Then $\begin{pmatrix} Y_1 \\Y_2\end{pmatrix} = L \begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\X_2\end{pmatrix}$

Then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are the required sequences